# How tweetstream gem in rails handle stall_warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, twitter, streaming, tweetstream

I am using the wonderful tweetstream gem ( https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream ) for rails to use the streaming twitter api.
However, i read in the twitter documentation that we can set the param "stall_warnings" to true in order to receive warning messages from twitter when the client is in danger of being disconnected, that tells how much the current client queue is full.( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#stall_warnings )

How can i use this feature with the tweetstream gem ?
I do not see anything in the tweetstream doc about it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

looking through the code on github:

https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream/blob/master/lib/tweetstream/client.rb

It might be the on_no_data_received method.

*"Set a Proc to be run when no data is received from the server
 and a stall occurs.  Twitter defines this to be 90 seconds."*

It doesn't explicitly say it's the same stall_warning from Twitter, but it does say this will proc when "a stall occurs".